# Segmentation fault while using structs and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stack

I want to implement some basic data structures in C in order to learn how to use pointers, but I got stuck in the first one; I have these two structs:

```
typedef struct node{
  int value;
  struct node* next;
}Node;


typedef struct stack{
  int qtd;
  Node* top;
}Stack;
```

And these functions:

```
Stack newStack(void){
  Stack tmp;
  tmp.qtd = 0;
  tmp.top = NULL;
  return tmp;
}

void push(Stack s, int value){
  if( s.qtd == 0 ){
    s.top->value = value; 
    s.qtd++;
  }
  else{
    Node* tmp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node*));
    tmp->value = value;
    tmp->next = s.top;
    s.top = tmp; 
    s.qtd++;
  }
}
```

In the `main()` function I "initialize" a stack (`Stack s = newStack();`)
and call the push function using (s,6) as parameters. I get a seg fault at `s.top->value = value;`. What's wrong?

Comment: Allocate memory for `s.top` before you dereference it.

Comment: You are operating on copies of `Stack` on the stack - even when you do allocate memory it's still going to be not quite right - you need to pass by reference.

Comment: C uses pass-by-value. The `push` function modifies a copy of its argument; I would guess that somewhere in code you didnt post, you do `push(a, b);` and expect `a` to be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were seeing segfault because `top` was initialized to `NULL` and then been dereferenced. Because you are implementing a stack, so every element got pushed onto the top, there is no need to check if it's empty or not in the `push` function.

Another problem, when allocating `Node`, it should be `sizeof(Node)`, you are just allocating a pointer, not a struct.

Also, you should pass `Stack` as a pointer to your stack, rather than the struct itself, because what you get inside the `push` function is a copy of the struct, so updating its field will not update the original structure.

Try this push function:

```
void push(Stack *s, int value) {
    Node* tmp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp->value = value;
    tmp->next = s->top;
    s->top = tmp;
    s->qtd++;
}
```

and allocate the stack by:

```
Stack* newStack(void) {
    Stack *s = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    s->qtd = 0;
    s->top = NULL;
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've just constructed the Stack `s` so `s.top` is NULL. Then you do this:

```
s.top->value = value;
```

Dereferencing a null pointer is *undefined behavior.* You're lucky all you got was a segfault.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the things already mentioned, you should also check the return value of malloc, so

```
Node* tmp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
if (tmp == NULL)
{
    return; 
}
```

as malloc is not guaranteed to succeed, this is especially concerning when you work on devices with low memory.